# Create new table for Spreecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm trying to create a new table for Spreecommerce, but always return me an error.

```
:006 > create_table(:Company)
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_table' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
    from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying with the command `create_table(:Company)` and with the command `rails generate model Company name:string history:string`
But always display an error

Comment: what error do you get when do **rails generate model**?. After you run `rails generate model` do you run migration created? `rake db:migrate`

Comment: yes, I excute this line, and when I excecute: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` is listed, and when I excecute:  `ActiveRecord::Company` shows me `NoMethodError: undefined method `Company' for ActiveRecord:Module
from (irb):3
from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'`

Comment: To Access your model just do something like **Company.new** or **Company.all** give a look to http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Thanks! I had use the command `reload`, thanks for help me